# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.compat.v2.tpu.experimental' has no attribute 'HardwareFeature'

Tags: tensorflow2.0

Running below code gave the error as `AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.compat.v2.tpu.experimental' has no attribute 'HardwareFeature'`

```
import os
import pprint
import tempfile

from typing import Dict, Text

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

!pip install -q tensorflow-recommenders

import tensorflow_recommenders as tfrs
```

tensorflow version used was `2.9.1` and the code was run from Google Colab

Answer (score 1):

Did a trial and error changed the order of execution as below and it worked fine no errors this time

```
!pip install -q tensorflow-recommenders

import os
import pprint
import tempfile

from typing import Dict, Text

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

import tensorflow_recommenders as tfrs
```